# Cholesky decomposition given an initial factorization $RR^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a rectangular matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times{}n}$, I am interested in computing the Cholesky factorization of $RR^{T}$. From what I understand the decomposition requires $\frac{1}{3}m^3$ FLOPS given an initial $\mathbb{R}^{m\times{}m}$ positive semidefinite matrix. But from an initial factorization $RR^{T}$, is it possible to achieve sub-cubic runtime using a modified variant of Cholesky?

Comment: Do you have $R$ to start or $RR^T$? Because you would not want to calculate $RR^T$ and then do factorization of that. You would want to perform QR factorization of $R$. $R=TU \Rightarrow RR^T = TUU^TT^T = TT^T$. $UU^T=I$ is the orthogonal factor from the QR, and $T$ is the triangular factor of the QR factorization of $R^T$.

Comment: @adamW: $R$ is given at the outset. Though QR decomposition is cubic in runtime, the suggested method still cuts down the number of operations required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a rectangular matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times{}n}$, looking for the Cholesky factorization of $RR^T$, rather than computing $RR^T$, compute:

$$ R^T = U^TT^T$$
with the QR factorization. Using $UU^T=I$ as the unitary factor, and $T$ the triangular factor:
$$RR^T = TUU^TT^T = T\cdot I \cdot T^T = TT^T$$
gives the Cholesky factorization of $RR^T$, avoiding any need to actually compute the multiple $RR^T$. This is not sub-cubic runtime, but it does avoid an unnecessary multiplication step.